# aggregate function in TSQL PIVOT

Tags: t-sql, pivot

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(SQL.105).aspx

In some cases I have seen the aggregate function as sum, Max or avg. How to determin which aggregate function to use in the PIVOT statement?
Thank you,
smith

Comment: It depends on your requirement. Do you have one?

Answer (score 3):

You can use any aggregate function in the `PIVOT` but it depends on what your requirement is for the query.

[Aggregate Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) include:

```
SUM()
MIN()
MAX()
COUNT()
AVG()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617713/how-to-create-a-pivottable-in-transact-sql In the above case I had "condition_result" as int data type. It worked. After changing to bit data type it stopped working. Why? How to decide which aggregate function is right. Thank you

Comment: @LaysomeSmith I am not sure what you are asking in referencing your other question.

Comment: @LaysomeSmith if you are using a bit field, then you need to wrap it in a `CASE` statement to get a value for the field. See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3769/2) with demo

Comment: Why? Is bit field (true or false) is not an value? I have seen examples that field returns Null also. Still I am not getting. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Most of the aggregate functions will not work with a `bit` datatype. What do you need to do?  That will help you decide which function to use.