# Access to sql crosstab query to sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

I am trying to convert this access query to sql 2008

Can anyone convert this access query to sql?

```
TRANSFORM Sum(q_INTERMONTH_Union_ILIs.Total) AS SumOfTotal
SELECT q_INTERMONTH_Union_ILIs.[Billable Identifier], 
   q_INTERMONTH_Union_ILIs.[Entity Identifier]
FROM q_INTERMONTH_Union_ILIs
GROUP BY q_INTERMONTH_Union_ILIs.[Billable Identifier], 
   q_INTERMONTH_Union_ILIs.[Entity Identifier]
PIVOT q_INTERMONTH_Union_ILIs.Period;
```

but getting this error...
anyone help

Comment: Can you supply sample data and desire output?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617713/how-to-create-a-pivottable-in-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

You current query in SQL Server will be similar to this:

```
select *
from
(
  SELECT q_INTERMONTH_Union_ILIs.[Billable Identifier], 
    q_INTERMONTH_Union_ILIs.[Entity Identifier],
    q_INTERMONTH_Union_ILIs.Period
  FROM q_INTERMONTH_Union_ILIs
) src
pivot
(
  Sum(Total)
  for Period in (yourPeriodValues go here)
) piv
```

In this line:

```
for Period in (yourPeriodValues go here)
```

You will place the values that you want as the columns inside of the parentheses `(yourPeriodValues go here)`.

Comment: What ever I put in (yourPeriodValues go here) I get this error:
"The column prefix 'q_INTERMONTH_Union_ILIs' does not match with a table name or alias named used in the query" and it repeats 2 time

Comment: @user2023568 see my edit, I the table name needs to be removed from the `pivot` part.