# Stored procedure from multiple rows into multiple columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is my current data:

```
GID, AppID, GName, GDesig, GBusinessName
101   3002   A     JO       AB House
102   3002   B     EO       BD Ltd
```

I need to mention that the number of rows may be 1 to 4. I want to show this record like this:

```
GID, AppID, GName, GDesig, GBusinessName, GName, GDesig, GBusinessName
101   3002   A     JO       AB House      B      EO       BD Ltd
```

How can I do this with a stored procedure? If any one give me any solution, that will be helpful for me.

Thanks

Nur

Comment: IS the GID in the second set from the first i.e 101? Do you just want to lose the other GIDs i.e. 102, 103 or 104 in the result set?

Comment: I want just these column and these are enough for me :: AppID, GName, GDesig, GBusinessName, GName, GDesig, GBusinessName

Comment: Thomas beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention what should be unique to each row in the output. I assumed it should be `AppId`. Given that, the trick is the `Partition By` where you rank each row for each grouping of AppId. What you seek is a crosstab. Given that you said there can be up to four rows for each group, we can build a static crosstab from that.

```
;With RnkItems As
    (
    Select GID, AppId, GName, GDesig, GBusinessName
        , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By AppId Order By GID, GName ) As Rnk
    From SourceData
    )
Select AppId
    , Min( Case When Rnk = 1 Then GName End ) As GName1
    , Min( Case When Rnk = 1 Then GDesig End ) As GDesig1
    , Min( Case When Rnk = 1 Then GBusinessName End ) As GBusinessName1

    , Min( Case When Rnk = 2 Then GName End ) As GName2
    , Min( Case When Rnk = 2 Then GDesig End ) As GDesig2
    , Min( Case When Rnk = 2 Then GBusinessName End ) As GBusinessName2

    , Min( Case When Rnk = 3 Then GName End ) As GName3
    , Min( Case When Rnk = 3 Then GDesig End ) As GDesig3
    , Min( Case When Rnk = 3 Then GBusinessName End ) As GBusinessName3

    , Min( Case When Rnk = 4 Then GName End ) As GName4
    , Min( Case When Rnk = 4 Then GDesig End ) As GDesig4
    , Min( Case When Rnk = 4 Then GBusinessName End ) As GBusinessName4
From RnkItems
Group By AppId
```

[SQL Fiddle version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/229e7/1)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use Pivot tables to achieve the result too

[How to create a PivotTable in Transact/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617713/how-to-create-a-pivottable-in-transact-sql)