# TSQL Pivot Table Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot-table

I have a attempted pivot table that follows:

```
 SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 
      [SurveyID]
      ,[SurveyQuestion]
      ,[SurveyQuestionID]
      ,[SequenceNumber]      
  FROM [Succession_Tool].[dbo].[SurveyQuestions]
) X
PIVOT
(
    SUM([SurveyID]) FOR [SurveyQuestion] IN (A,B,C)
) Z
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 325, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.
```

I tried to rewrite it based on some other articles on stackoverflow and other places such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617713/how-to-create-a-pivottable-in-transact-sql) or [this](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/create-pivoted-tables-3-steps) but they both lead back to the same error above.  Is there something simple I'm missing?  For what its worth, my compatibility_level is 100, this is SQL Serer 2008, I don't need the aggregation because just want the formatting to spit out to a CSV file

UPDATE:  I rewrote the query again below following [these](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/create-pivoted-tables-3-steps) directions

```
 WITH MYSurveyQuestions AS 
(SELECT 
      [SurveyID]
      ,[SurveyQuestion]
      ,[SurveyQuestionID]
      ,[SequenceNumber]      
  FROM [Succession_Tool].[dbo].[SurveyQuestions]
) 
SELECT * FROM MYSurveyQuestions
PIVOT   
(SUM(SURVEYID) FOR SurveyQuestion
    IN (A,B,C,D,E,F)) AS PVT
```

Now I get the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11 Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Unfortunately, that has the same meaning as the first error to me because I still can't find the error(shrug)...I feel like I'm closer though.  Double clicking the error highlights

> (SUM(SURVEYID) FOR SurveyQuestion

Comment: What result do you get when you run `SELECT @@VERSION`?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)   Jun 28 2012 08:36:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)   @GarethD

Comment: Both the current database and the one you are selecting from should have the correct compatibility level.

Comment: Actually I was mistaken, only the current database must have the required compatibility level. The other one(s) (e.g. `Succession_Tool` in your example) doesn't have to. So, just as the message said, it was probably the current database, whatever it was, that needed fixing.

Comment: All data is coming from the same database(Succession_Tool), which has a level of 100

Comment: Don't you need square brackets (or single quotes) around the letters in parentheses?  [A],[B] etc.

Comment: Same error with square brackets (single quotes throws a error), Thanks @influent

Comment: Shot in the dark but did you try "select * from sys.databases" to see all the compatibility levels according to that view?

Comment: @influent, yes that particular database I'm hitting is 100 and that is the only source I hit.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks, just making sure Mgmt Studio wasn't lying.

Comment: Never mind where the data were coming from, was `Succession_Tool` the *current* database when you were running the query? If not, what compatibility level did the database that was current have?

Comment: The succession_Tool is the only and current database the data is coming from and the compatibility level is 100, Thanks @AndriyM

Comment: The reason why it didn't work is because what @AndriyM and "influent" suggested earlier, it was a compatibility_level problem, but all my fault still.  I was unknowningly connected to another database that had a Level of 80, but didn't realize it because I had a fully qualified database name.  Succession_Tool has a Level of 100.  One of you should post this as a answer so you can get credit for it.  My apologies for such a simple problem, thank you all for your help.