# Combine output in SQL into single row

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL Query that uses an ID to select a bunch of related rows. However, rather than a single row for each of the associated items I would like to concatenate them into a single row.

For example rather than:

```
ID    Item
1     a
2     b
1     c
```

I would like:

```
ID    Item 1    Item 2    ...
1     a         c
2     b
```

Currently I am using a simple query but can't figure out how to do this:

```
Select
    Investigation.ID,
    Record.Item
FROM 
    Investigation
INNER JOIN 
    Record
    ON Investigation.ID = Record.Inv_Id
```

This query is all part of a much larger one that involves multiple joins and a union. Eventually this will all be converted to XML in a format that hopefully resembles something like this:

```
<investigation>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>something</name>
    <items>
        <item>a</item>
        <item>c</item>
    </items>
<investigation>
<investigation>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>something else</name>
    <items>
        <item>b</item>
    </items>
</investigation>
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but this looks like a case for a pivot.

Comment: Please take a look at the following question. It uses the PIVOT and will get the results you require. Also explaining how to create a dynamic pivot statement if your values are not always known. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617713/how-to-create-a-pivottable-in-transact-sql

Comment: I'll look into just a bit worried about performance as it would have to be a dynamic pivot included in an already complex sql query. Thank you :)

Comment: does to work for you if it returns the items as comma separated? if you have dynamic number of "Items" then "STUFF" and "coalesce" could work for you... let me know if that works so that i give you the solution

Comment: Unfortunately not, the XML is generated from the query so it would just make them all one XML field. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

Took some efforts to do this But this should work

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[Id]) 
            FROM [Investigation] c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT [Id], ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select id, item, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY id order by item asc) as uid
                from [Investigation]
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MIN(item)
                for [uid] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)

print @query
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a subquery. I did look at your answer Pravin but I didn't understand it and couldn't make it work. This is my first time dipping into SQL since three years ago at university so I'm very rusty. This worked for me at least for a single table query:

```
SELECT ( SELECT * FROM ( 
    Select Investigation.ID as ID,
        (SELECT ( SELECT * FROM ( select
            Record.item
            FROM Investigation as Inv
            INNER JOIN Record
            ON Inv.ID = Record.Inv_Id
            WHERE Inv.ID = Investigations.ID
        )
        AS temp FOR xml path(''), type )
    ) AS Items
from dbo.Investigation
) AS xmlextract FOR xml path ('Investigation'), 
root('root') )AS xmlextract
```

It produces output like this:

```
<root>
    <Investigation>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Items>
            <item>a</item> 
            <item>c</item>
        </Items>
    </Investigation>
    <Investigation>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Items>
            <item>b</item>
        </Items>
    </Investigation>
</root>
```

Now onto the next problem of the union causing me to be unable to use the xml data type :P

Comment: Can you please share the outcome you got with my query ?