# Pivot on fields with count of entries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table that needs to be converted into a pivot both fields contain the same entries and a count of the entries need to be represented in a pivot table. The count of the entries has to done as groupings by entry types such as A or B.

Table

```
   X   Y
-----------
   A   B    
   A   C    
   D   B    
   B   C    
   C   C    
   D   E    
   D   B    
   F   C
```

Pivot

```
         A Or B   C Or D   E Or F
A Or B     1        2        0
C Or D     2        1        1
E Or F     0        1        0
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a PivotTable in Transact/SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617713/how-to-create-a-pivottable-in-transact-sql)

Comment: the example does not handle the grouping of data entries.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build a dynamic query if your groups are dynamic.

```
declare @t table(X char(1), Y char(1))
insert into @t values
('A', 'B')
, ('A', 'C')
, ('D', 'B')
, ('B', 'C')
, ('C', 'C')
, ('D', 'E')
, ('D', 'B')
, ('F', 'C')

Select [\] = G2, isnull([A Or B], 0), isnull([C Or D], 0), isnull([E Or F], 0) 
From (
    Select G1 = g1.name, G2 = g2.name, total = count(*) From @t t
    Inner Join (values('A Or B', 'A', 'B'), ('C Or D', 'C', 'D'), ('E Or F', 'E', 'F')) g1(name, X, Y) on t.X = g1.X or t.X = g1.Y
    Inner Join (values('A Or B', 'A', 'B'), ('C Or D', 'C', 'D'), ('E Or F', 'E', 'F')) g2(name, X, Y) on t.Y = g2.X or t.Y = g2.Y
    Group By g1.name, g2.name
) as d
Pivot (
    max(total)
    For G1 In ([A Or B], [C Or D], [E Or F])
) as piv
```